# Java - Modulo Addition of Bytes

Tags: java, byte, modulo

I'm trying to perform modulo addition with two bytes in java, getting a third byte as a result.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
public static byte modAdd(byte byte1,byte byte2){
    int int1 = ((int)byte1)+128;
    int int2 = ((int)byte2)+128;
    int outNum = int1+int2;
    if(outNum>255){
        outNum-=255;
    }
    outNum-=128;
    return (byte)outNum;
}
```

However, this has problem cases - when byte1 is 0x7F, and byte2 is anything but 0x00, my modulo subtraction code doesn't return 0x7F - it returns 0x80 instead.

I can identify the case, but I don't know how to go about fixing it.

Comment: What is `out[]`? What is `i`? You seem to use `out` as an array, but return it in a method that returns `byte`: looks like your code cannot be compiled. Also, what is your expected result when you call, say, `modAdd(0x7F, 0x03)`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that `(byte)((byte1+byte2) & 0xff)` doesn't already do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just replace that function with byte1 + byte2.  Integer addition, regardless of integer size, yields "modular" overflow by design.  There is no need for all of that casting.

The cause of the error you found is in this line:

```
    outNum-=255;
```

That should be 256